# Strange apt(-get) proxy authentication behavior

Tags: networking, apt, firefox, proxy

I've installed Ubuntu18.04 to my company's PC. And I've set the configuration to connect internet through company's proxy such like;

`/etc/environment`

```
http_proxy="http://user%40domain:pass@proxy.ip:port/"
https_proxy="https://user%40domain:pass@proxy.ip:port/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://user%40domain:pass@proxy.ip:port/"
```

`/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user%40domain:pass@proxy.ip:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://user%40domain:pass@proxy.ip:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://user%40domain:pass@proxy.ip:port/";
```

And then I could connect internet and do apt command such like `sudo apt-get update`.

But when the next day is coming, I can't do apt command.

```
Err:1 http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: proxy.ip port]
Err:2 http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease  
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: proxy.ip port]
Err:3 http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: proxy.ip port]
Err:4 http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease               
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: proxy.ip port]
```

**But!!** If I open firefox from GUI, this problem was resolved...
It was too strange and I can't understand this behavior...

Firefox settings are `Use system proxy settings`.

I asked my company administrator for proxy server about this problem, our proxy server seems to reboot every night.
Could you please explain why this behavior was occurred and how can I do apt command **everyday** without opening firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a google search trip for long time, I found a solution finally...

The answer is opening firefox with headless mode everyday using shell script!
This may not be elegant answer but I can pass our company's proxy anyway :(

Here is my script in `~/open_firefox.sh`;

```
# open url via firefox
firefox https://google.com --headless & disown

# wait 3s
sleep 3

# kill above process
pkill -f firefox
```

And then, register crontab by `crontab -e`;

```bsh
0 2 * * * $HOME/open_firefox.sh
```

Of course, don't forget to give execute permission.

```bsh
sudo chmod +x ~/open_firefox.sh
```

Comment: If that is an answer to your question, go ahead and select it as such.